# Google Analytics Kiosk: URL that compares current month to last, and is permalink

Tags: google-analytics, reporting

We have a kiosk that runs all the time.  We display the overview report with this month vs last month comparison.  But I have to come in and refresh the page and reset the period every day.

Is there a way I can form a URL that accomplishes this goal and will update accordingly when I refresh the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google analytics does not support changing the default date range or saving a month over month comparison.   This question gets asked quite a bit, and I wish they would support it.

The only solution to this appears to be to bookmark a month over month comparison view that has static dates in it, and then create a bookmarklet that will calculate the current dates to put in there send you there.

Here are some sites show how to do this:

http://whiletruecode.com/post/change-the-default-google-analytics-date-range-with-a-bookmarklet

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509010/bookmark-with-date-in-the-url

http://ratafia.info/post/70509179/bookmarklet-to-show-todays-stats-in-google-analytics

EDIT: Some of the above links are out of date (Google changed the URL format of dates in Analytics URLs at some point).  I created a page that can on my site that can be bookmarked with your Google Analytics report id to get a wide variety of links for various time periods: http://ostermiller.org/calc/ga.html

Comment: Thanks Steve -- nice to see you, too.  I normally hang out on SO :-)